# facebook app meta tags cached?

Tags: tags, meta

i have created an Open graph storie on my facebook app. I want to to integrate the code to my website...

this is the meta tags i use

```
     <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# rovespier: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/rovespier#">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="349547121879416" />
<meta property="og:type" content="rovespier:art" />
<meta property="og:url" content="Put your own URL to the object here" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php $message; ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rovespier.com/uploads/videos/images/142367443594.jpg" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

i used facebook debugger. the thing is that (because i use this code for mulptiple pages) in some pages the open graph shows ok but in some shows values like 'sample video' or another image from the one i specified on the meta tag or no image at all. Any idea why is that? Sounds kind of crazy

Answer (score 0):

Start adding a width and a heigt to your og:image. If there is no image width or height set, it may take another image than the one that is defiend.

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
```